# Ask a question about probability calculation in statistics

Tags: integration, statistics

Suppose that the time to death X has an exponential distribution with hazard rate $\lambda$ and that the right-censoring time C is exponential with hazard rate $\theta$. Let T = min(X,C) and $\delta$ = 1 if X $\leq$ C;

0,if X > C. Assume that X and C are independent. Show that $\delta$ and T are independent.

My attempt:

We only need to show that

$P(\delta=1, T>t)= P(\delta=1) P(T>t)$, for any non-negative t, and $P(\delta=0, T>t)= P(\delta=0) P(T>t)$.

$P(\delta=1, T>t)= P(X \leq C, T>t)= P(X \leq C, \min(X,C)>t) = P(X \leq C, X>t,C>t)= P(X \leq C, X>t | C>t) P(C>t)$,

The second term is easy to find since C is exponential distributed. I find $P(C>t) = e^{- \theta t}$. I am stuck with the first term.

$P(X \leq C, X>t | C>t) = \int_{s=t}^\infty P(X \leq C, X>t | C=S) ds = \int_{s=t}^\infty P(X \leq S, X>t | C=S) ds = \int_{s=t}^\infty P(X \leq S, X>t) ds$ since X and C are independent.

Then I find $P(X \leq S, X>t) = e^{- \lambda t} - e^{- \lambda s}$. Then I plug this value back, I get $\int_{s=t}^\infty (e^{- \lambda t} - e^{- \lambda s}) ds$, which the first term gives me infinity, which is wrong.

Comment: I would have thought you could show $P(\delta=1, T>t) =\lambda e^{-(\lambda+\delta)t} = P(\delta=1) P(T>t)$

Comment: @Henry I don't think your calculation is correct.

Comment: Indeed it might not be (I may have confused the pdf and cdf in my mental calculation) and perhaps should have written $\int\limits_{c=t}^\infty \int\limits_{x=t}^c \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \theta e^{-\theta c}\, dx \, dc =\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\delta} e^{-(\lambda+\delta)t} $.  Still $= P(\delta=1) P(T>t)$

Comment: Yes, your calcualtion is correct. But can you point out where my mistake is?

Comment: I am not sure your statement  $P(X \leq C, X>t | C>t) = \int_{s=t}^\infty P(X \leq C, X>t | C=S) ds$ is correct

Comment: Yes, maybe this step is not legal. I am not sure.